# NEXT JS Images are not loading when their path is in a variable

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, frontend, jsx

I have am using Next js to code. I have an array of images I want to use in my application.

CODE1

```
<Image src={require("../assets/image1.png")} />
when I code it like this, the image loads perfectly
```

but if I try this;
CODE2

```
const path= "../assets/image1.png"
<Image src={require(path)} />
```

Next js throws an error code that module not found.
*Error: Cannot find module '../assets/image1.png'*

I even tried

```
<Image src={require(`"${path}"`)} />
```

I still get an error.
*Error: Cannot find module '"../assets/image1.png"'*

And I have also tried to put a backslash before the path eg.
const path = "/../assets/image1.png"*
that also gives me an error

NB: In all three instances, the path of the image remains the same but only code 1 works. As soon as I put the path in a variable or an array. Any help would greatly be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I think what your trying to do, won't be possible. `require` can't work with dynamic paths.

You can do

```
const path= require("../assets/image1.png")
<Image src={path} />
```

But I would recommend, placing the static images inside the `public` folder
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

And you can directly use them, inside the image component, by simple passing the path.

```
<Image src="/image1.png" />
```